# Save captured image into directory

Tags: jquery, image, canvas

I am trying to capture div content and save as an image using canvas ,

here is my code :

```
$(function() { 
    $("#proceed").click(function() { 
      html2canvas($("#wrap"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                      window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It opens my div content as an image in new tab , but how can I store this image into directory?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to download the captured stream into you os-file-system?

Comment: First hit in Google: http://jsfiddle.net/wboykinm/fL0q2uce/

Comment: I want to save it to mysite.com/upload/user_id/test.png

Comment: You would need to send the file from the client to the server, and then have some server side code on the receiving end to process that image. You cannot do this in JS alone.

Comment: I hope `captureStream` is a typo, this will return a MediaStream, not a fixed image. But since you're not calling it correctly, I'm confident this is a typo...

Comment: yes, it was a typo. question edited